# Django REST framework API only working from the API project

Tags: ajax, django, api

I am developing a REST API for my application with `django-rest-framework`.

Everything works fine as long as I use either:

- The browsable API
- AJAX requests within a template in the same project where the API is being built

If I try to access the API from oustide the "master" project (the one I am building an API for), for instance from another Django project on the same machine, I am constantly getting an error.

Here is the trace from `runserver` for a **successful** API call:

```
[21/Nov/2014 12:11:01] "GET /api/test_session/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9208
```

The same endpoint but from outside the master project (it **fails**):

```
[21/Nov/2014 12:11:14] "GET /api/test_session/ HTTP/1.1" 200 58
```

I am using the `ajax` function of jQuery to send my API calls and I have set up the `error` callback. However the `errorThrown` that I receive is empty and the `textStatus` property only says "error".

How do I access my API from the oustide? I am using the default authentification backend (session based).

Comment: A 200 response suggests a successful response.  Is it the form of the response that fails?  If so, please show the difference.

Comment: Indeed the web server returns 200. But $.ajax() triggers the `error` callback and not `success`. Said differently, I am not getting the expected JSON response when I call the API from outside the main project. On the other hand, if I make *the exact same call* in a raw html page (using `TemplateView`) from the main project, then `success` is triggered and I receive the expected JSON message.

Comment: Then your problem isn't the REST API but the Javascript.  Did you check by hand if you can make the external call with ipython and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (or something similar)?

Comment: `requests.get` works fine: 200 status code and the expected JSON response.

Comment: Then you have a bug in the javascript.

Comment: But the exact same Javascript code works if I run it on a page from the main project. It does not make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65376/discussion-between-beltiras-and-buddyshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion it came to light that the error had to do with [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policies.

Answer (score 0):

A solution tailored for Django is to use [django-cors-header](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/), as recommended by the [django REST framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors).